# How to retrieve content value from Microdata meta tag inside a class

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, meta-tags, microdata

I am trying to retrive all the values of the `dateCreated`.

I am using Selenium webdriver with Python.

```html
<div class="bv-content-datetime" role="presentation">
    <meta itemprop="dateCreated" content="2018-08-28"> -- this one
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2018-08-28"> 
<span class="bv-content-datetime-dot" aria-hidden="true">·</span> 
<span class="bv-content-datetime-stamp">vor 11 Monaten &nbsp;</span> </div>
```

I have been trying to retrieve "2018-08-28".

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried - `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[itemprop="dateCreated"]').get_attribute('content' `
this works fine for a single element. but when I try to retrieve all the elements by "find_element**s**_by_css_selector", it returns nothing. Am I doing it wring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_attribute('content')`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[itemprop="dateCreated"]').get_attribute('content')
```

**EDIT:**

use for loop for n number of elements.

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[itemprop="dateCreated"]'):
  print(item.get_attribute('content'))
```

Comment: thanks @KunduK this works fine for a single element. but when I try to retrieve all the elements by "find_element**s**_by_css_selector", it returns nothing.
Am I doing it wring?

Comment: you are a lifesaver :D